# Error when install python mysql module on windows?

Tags: python, mysql, windows

When i try to install mysql on windows i get this error

```
MySQL-python-0.9.2>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: what happens when you try  > python setup.py install ?

Comment: When i instlal i get this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, you don't have visual c++ compiler installed or compiler not in the PATH.

If you have mingw32, you can pass paramter `-c mingw32`

And mysql-python is available as [binary in windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.2/MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.5.exe/download), you may not need to compile yourself.

**UPDATE**: OP is using python 2.6, no binaries for 1.2.3 in mysql-python page for windows.

[Here](http://soemin.googlecode.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.6.exe) is the one I have compiled before

Comment: how can i check for that compiler? or from where i have to install that compiler?

Comment: Yes, MySQL-python core is written in C, also need MySQL header files, so you need some compiler but I think its hard to do that if you are not sure about compiling yourself, what is your python version and you want mysql-python 0.9.2 only? why not 1.2.2 or 1.2.3? Anyway, If you could provide that info I can suggest better.

Comment: ok, for mysql-python 1.2.3 and python2.6, mysql-python page does not have windows binary, but I have compile it before, you can download here. http://soemin.googlecode.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.6.exe